# Open Manipulator python API documentation, or Examples

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python, manipulator, rosservice

As stated by the title, is there a way I can access to the python API documentation of the Open Manipulator package? Right now all I can find are service definition such as:

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_x/ros_controller_msg/#message-list

Which has the following info:

[image: Example service definition]

But I don't know how to call it in Python, nor what's the definition of `kinematics_pose`.

I managed to get one example from here: https://github.com/DougUOW/om_service_call_examples/blob/master/src/single_movement.py

```py
import rospy
import sys
from open_manipulator_msgs.srv import SetJointPosition, SetJointPositionRequest

rospy.init_node('service_set_joint_position_client')
rospy.wait_for_service('/goal_joint_space_path')
goal_joint_space_path_service_client = rospy.ServiceProxy('/goal_joint_space_path', SetJointPosition)
goal_joint_space_path_request_object = SetJointPositionRequest()

goal_joint_space_path_request_object.planning_group = 'arm'
goal_joint_space_path_request_object.joint_position.joint_name = ['joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3', 'joint4']
goal_joint_space_path_request_object.joint_position.position = [0.0, -1, 0.3, 0.7]
goal_joint_space_path_request_object.joint_position.max_accelerations_scaling_factor = 1.0
goal_joint_space_path_request_object.joint_position.max_velocity_scaling_factor = 1.0
goal_joint_space_path_request_object.path_time = 2.0

rospy.loginfo("Doing Service Call...")

result = goal_joint_space_path_service_client(goal_joint_space_path_request_object)

print result
```

But as you can see, it's using some library definitions (`SetJointPosition` and `SetJointPositionRequest`) which I have trouble at finding.

So in short, are you supposed to get a pattern on your own or is there an actual documentation for this?

By "get a pattern" I meant for example for Kinematics, I'd import `SetKinematicsPose` and `SetKinematicsPoseRequest`.